# Unhandled promise rejection when trying to throw error in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am implementing a piece of code which goes through project's build and checks if there are multiple pages with `featured: true`. If that is a case, I want to throw an error, so that `qa` job in a pipeline would fail. Everything would work fine but I am getting:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()
```

this is my code:

```js
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-syntax */
const fs = require('fs');
const findInDir = require('./utils/findInDir');

(async () => {
  const dir = './public/page-data/blog';
  const fileRegex = /.*/;
  const allFiles = findInDir(dir, fileRegex);
  let result = 0;

  for (const file of allFiles) {
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
      const data = await fs.promises.readFile(file);
      const obj = JSON.parse(data);

      if (obj.result.pageContext.featured === true) {
        result += 1;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // noop
    }
  }

  if (result > 1) {
    throw new Error('There are multiple featured blog posts, please fix.');
  }
})();
```

How can I throw an error in async function?

Comment: You *are* throwing an error in the async function, which is exactly why you're seeing that message. That message says you threw an error in an async function, *and that wasn't handled anywhere.*

Comment: Your outer `async` wrapper has NO error handling on it at all, so if you let a rejected promise get there, then you will get the `UnhandlePromiseRejectionWarning`.  Either catch all errors before they get out of your `async` function wrapper or put error handling on that wrapper.

Comment: Also `findInDir` might be throwing an error

Comment: What do you mean by "*so that `qa` job in a pipeline would fail*"? How is that job calling your script? And what do you need to do to make it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can error can be handled with a catch block, like this:-

```
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-syntax */
const fs = require('fs');
const findInDir = require('./utils/findInDir');

(async () => {
  const dir = './public/page-data/blog';
  const fileRegex = /.*/;
  const allFiles = findInDir(dir, fileRegex);
  let result = 0;

  for (const file of allFiles) {
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
      const data = await fs.promises.readFile(file);
      const obj = JSON.parse(data);

      if (obj.result.pageContext.featured === true) {
        result += 1;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // noop
    }
  }

  if (result > 1) {
    throw new Error('There are multiple featured blog posts, please fix.');
  }
})().catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Arguably, in this case, why are you throwing in the first place instead of just putting the `console.log` into the `if (result > 1)`…?

Comment: Agreed! My intention is just to show that how to handle error in this type functions.

Comment: @deceze There might be other points in the function that throw an exception